# ORA-22295 processing clob and long together

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I'm trying to load 2 clob and one long column in a single insert statement. I'm getting error message as

> ORA-22295: cannot bind more than 4000 bytes data to LOB and LONG columns in 1 statement.

After browsing about this error code I understood that we can't process clob and long data type together. Either one long or all/any clob can only be processed in a single statement. So Does this mean I have to first insert for all my clob columns and following that I have to trigger an update sql to load the long column. Please advise me in this.

I dont have the source code as I'm processing the rows using data stage etl tool.

Comment: You shouldn't use the `LONG` datatype, it's [deprecated](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#i45885). Can you convert your table columns to CLOB?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you will have to use some form of two statements per row to accomplish this.

Since you face having to do so much heavy lifting, this is the perfect time to eliminate the LONG column in the destination data source.